# What are the AdS/CFT papers which study the stringy effects in the bulk?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, resource-recommendations, ads-cft

I would like to know of a list of pedagogical/classic/nice papers that study stringy effects in the bulk. May be a sequence which a student follows to understand the stringy nature that is at play.

Comment: This strikes me as too broad as is, but it could be modified a bit to fit under our [recommendation policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed) I think.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+[books]+ads%2Fcft

Comment: In my expectation, a description of exclusively stringy effects in the bulk in the context of the AdS/CFT business should rather be quite specific (excitations). So the question does not look too broad to me.

Comment: If it is specific, then this is a reference request. But it's not as specific as most reference requests as it is not addressing a particular study, more of a class of studies. As a resource recommendation it seems too narrow. Not sure, bring this up on meta if you wish, @Dilaton. There is a fuzzy region between ref-req and resource-req that is not clear policywise.